# How do I customize a LiveCD that can only "Try Ubuntu"?

Tags: boot, live-cd, ubiquity, custom-distributions

This is what I'm looking to do:

Create a LiveCD that only can Try Ubuntu, can't install the OS at all. Boots directly to `Try Ubuntu`. I need to have certain packages on that LiveCD, such as fsarchiver , hwinfo, etc and some Perl scripts. No GUI, just the good old CLI is all that's needed.

Preferably, I'd like to get a full install going, customize it from within (update it, install the packages I need, place the scripts where I need them, etc.) And then from that create a LiveCD that only boots up, with no install option at all.

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can remaster ubuntu without including ubiquity, I 'll add answer later if none answered this question :)

Comment: So would I do something like install Ubuntu, set it up how I need it, use remastersys to do a remaster of it, and then edit the syslinux.cfg to default to live? That's just a guess though of putting two separate posts together that I've read.

Comment: Since all you want is a CLI with a few packages included, you may achieve your objective easier with Knoppix/Gnoppix or even PuppyLinux (PuppyLinux is now based on Ubunto afaik). Not wanting to discourage you from using the Ubuntu distro, but just an idea which might meet the end result easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Remove the package `ubiquity` from a chrooted installation DVD.

Here are several answers on how to create a Live DVD: [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)